# remove double quotes is contains NULL from Json return data

Tags: json

I am getting Json data like following, but in the data it displays double quotes for NULL as well. It there a function to remove it?

```
{"errorcode":"0","data":[{"id":"196660","userid":"689763","available_points":"5",**"expire_date":"NULL"**,"add_date":"2015-04-08 06:36:15"}]}
```

it should returns:

```
{"errorcode":"0","data":[{"id":"196660","userid":"689763","available_points":"5",**"expire_date":NULL**,"add_date":"2015-04-08 06:36:15"}]}
```

How can I remove the double quote? Cheers.

Comment: Please post your current code.

Comment: Why do you want to remove double quotes. You can also fetch it and check like `expiry_date.equalsIgnoreCase("NULL")`

Answer (score 0):

NULL is illegal in JSON, so it should certainly not return NULL instead of "NULL". It should be null.

If possible, talk to whoever creates the data and tell them to produce null instead of "NULL". The obvious and very simple alternative is that when you expect a date, which will be received as a string anyway, check for the value "NULL" by hand.

Don't even think about manipulating the JSON data that you received. Someone *will* send you a string "NULL" somewhere that is expected to be treated as a string. It is much, much simpler and safer to manipulate the parsed results.

Answer (score 0):

Since March 2014, the revised RFC for the JSON spec would tell us this should be

```json
{"expire_date": null}
```

as that revision declared strings to be a "basic type" rather than a sequence (i.e. list) of characters.